# USA visa query for Indian divorcee

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, us-citizens

I am an Indian citizen and I have UK divorce papers. I will be getting married to a USA citizen. Do I need an Indian divorce certificate when applying for a USA visa?

Comment: @TheZealot do you have a reference for that?  Certainly US courts consider themselves competent to divorce people who were married in foreign jurisdictions.

Comment: Phoog her case is that of being married in one country, divorced in another, and applying through the notorious USCIS. I recommend an attorney.

Answer (score 1):

Technically your question is in the wrong part of Travel Exchange since you are considering a long term move. Should be under expatriates or law.

The answer [appears to be yes](https://info.legalzoom.com/file-divorce-got-married-overseas-20698.html). However for your complicated case I recommend getting a qualified immigration attorney.